# Google Compute Engine: How to recreate existing instances after instance templates updated, without having any downtime

Tags: google-compute-engine, gce-instance-group

I am looking at this document to create existing instances after I updated instance group with new instance template.

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instance-groups/managed/recreate-instances

I think, if I do this, existing instances will be down for a few minutes while they are being recreated with new instance template. What should I do to prevent downtime?

Thank you.

Update: Should I be using this, with Max surge and Max unavailable options?

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/updating-managed-instance-groups

Comment: I tried using this command, but site shows error 502 for a few seconds.  After  that, it is back with new updates. Is there any settings that I could update with no downtime at all?           gcloud alpha compute instance-groups managed update-instances [groupname] --action replace --version-new template=[templatename] --max-surge 3 --zone us-central1-b

Comment: Same thing happened with this command too;   gcloud alpha compute instance-groups managed update-instances  [groupname] --action replace --version-new template=[templatename] --max-surge 4 --max-unavailable 2 --zone us-central1-b